# Django. How to edit and save changes in json file?

Tags: python, json, django

I try to edit .json file and save it.
I don know how to write rest of code.
models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

edit.html

```
{%  for key, value in mydata.items %}
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="content">{{value}}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz">
    </form>
{%  endfor  %}
```

views.py - **EDITED** - works fine:

```
def edit(request, document_id=1):
    with open('/home/path/to/files/'+str(Document.objects.get(id=document_id).docfile.name), 'r+') as json_file:
        mydata = json.loads(json_file.read())
        if request.method == 'POST':
            for key in mydata:
                mydata[key] = request.POST.get('content', '')

        # Move the position to the begnning of the file
                json_file.seek(0)
        # Write object as JSON
                json_file.write(json.dumps(mydata))
        # Truncate excess file contents
                json_file.truncate()
                args = {}
                args['mydata'] = mydata
                args.update(csrf(request))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/specific_document/%s' % document_id, args)
        else:
            with open('/home/path/to/files/'+str(Document.objects.get(id=document_id).docfile.name), 'r') as json_file:
                mydata = json.loads(json_file.read())
            args = {}
            args['mydata'] = mydata
            args.update(csrf(request))

            return render_to_response('edit.html', args)
```

All works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you've deserialized the saved JSON file, so `mydata` is a Python object. You can modify it as you would any other Python object.

For example, to add the `textarea`'s content as a dictionary key:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    mydata['content'] = request.POST.get('content', '')

    # Move the position to the begnning of the file
    json_file.seek(0)
    # Write object as JSON
    json_file.write(json.dumps(mydata))
    # Truncate excess file contents
    json_file.truncate()
```

Note: If you're both reading and writing the contents of the file, the `mode` argument should be `r+` (not `w` as you wrote in the original). Invoking `read` on a file opened with `w` will cause a `IOError` exception in Python 2 and `io.UnsupportedOperation` exception in Python 3.

Comment: Using Your code i get ValueError I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @bartekch The snippet I provided needs to be indented inside the `with` statement. (The conclusion of `with` in this case automatically closes the file.)

Comment: Now I cleary understand how 'with' statement  works :) Thanx. I edit question, the edit() function works fine.